# IndexAxisValueFormatter not working as expected

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to create a bar chart. My configurations:

```
<string-array name="months_initials">
       <item>J</item>
       <item>F</item>
       <item>M</item>
       <item>A</item>
       <item>M</item>
       <item>J</item>
       <item>J</item>
       <item>A</item>
       <item>S</item>
       <item>O</item>
       <item>N</item>
       <item>D</item>
   </string-array>
```

...

```
String[] months = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months_initials);
chart.getXAxis().setCenterAxisLabels(true);
chart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(months.length, true);
chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(months) {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        Timber.i("index = %s", value);
        return super.getFormattedValue(value, axis);
    }
});
```

> index = 0.5
>   index = 1.5909091
>   index = 2.6818182
>   index = 3.7727275
>   index = 4.8636365
>   index = 5.9545455
>   index = 7.0454545
>   index = 8.136364
>   index = 9.227273
>   index = 10.318182
>   index = 11.409091

And this is the result:
[image]

Now, if I change it to: `return super.getFormattedValue(value-0.5f, axis);`

The result is:
[image]

Again, if I add another change: `chart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE, true);`

> index = 0.5
>   index = 1.0
>   index = 1.5
>   index = 2.0
>   index = 2.5
>   index = 3.0
>   index = 3.5
>   index = 4.0
>   index = 4.5
>   index = 5.0
>   index = 5.5
>   index = 6.0
>   index = 6.5
>   index = 7.0
>   index = 7.5
>   index = 8.0
>   index = 8.5
>   index = 9.0
>   index = 9.5
>   index = 10.0
>   index = 10.5
>   index = 11.0
>   index = 11.5
>   index = 12.0
>   index = 12.5

The result is:
[image]

A bit "hammer time" but it would work for me, unfortunately the labels are not correctly centered.
So, what's happening here, what am I missing? How can I achieve my final result?

Thanks for your time.

ps: opened an [issue](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3810) too.

**EDIT** full setup code:

```
    String[] months = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months_initials);
    BarChart chart = binding.barChart;

    chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    chart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE, true);
    chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(months) {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            Timber.i("index = %s", value);
            return super.getFormattedValue(value - 0.5f, axis);
        }
    });
    chart.getXAxis().setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.grey));
    chart.getXAxis().setTextSize(12);

    BarDataSet barData = new BarDataSet(data, "data");
    barData.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.chart_bar));
    barData.setDrawValues(false);

    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(barData);
    binding.barChart.setData(new BarData(dataSets));
    binding.barChart.animateY(1000, Easing.EasingOption.Linear);
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't exactly pin point the issue in your code but it is probably something do with the granularity of the chart.
But here's a rough working example. Hope this helps!

```
        String[] months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"};

        BarChart mChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barChart);
        mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
        mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        XAxis xaxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xaxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xaxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xaxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xaxis.setDrawLabels(true);
        xaxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        xaxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(months));

        YAxis yAxisLeft = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        yAxisLeft.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART);
        yAxisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false);
        yAxisLeft.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        yAxisLeft.setEnabled(false);

        mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

        Legend legend = mChart.getLegend();
        legend.setEnabled(false);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(i, (i+1)*10);
            valueSet1.add(entry);
        }

        List<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, " ");
        barDataSet.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        barDataSet.setDrawValues(false);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet);

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.invalidate();
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think granularity is the key since all touch events from the chart are disabled, without zooming granularity is "ignored".
I've added the full setup code.

Comment: One other thing you could try is, removing this line `chart.getXAxis().setCenterAxisLabels(true);` This is mostly useful in the case of grouped bar charts for centering labels between adjacent bars.

Comment: If I remove that line the labels align between bars ("white column").

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and resolved by doing this :

```
barChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(barDataSet.getEntryCount());
```

Moreover if you are using only one dataset then instead of this:

```
ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add(barData);
```

Use:

```
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(yourValauesHere, "Legend Text here");
```

For reference please follow example below:

```
    barEntries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(0, 1));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1, 2));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(2, 4));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(3, 6));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(4, 5));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(5, 7));

    barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Contracts");
    barDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    barDataSet.setColor(getColor("defaultYellow"));
    barDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    barDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
    barDataSet.setValueTextSize(defaultValueTextSize);
    barDataSet.setValueTextColor(getColor("primaryDark"));

    BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);

    barChart.getDescription().setText("No. of Contracts signed in 6 
    months");
    barChart.getDescription().setTextSize(12);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0);
    barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
    barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new 
    IndexAxisValueFormatter(getXAxisValues()));
    barChart.animateY(1000);
    barChart.setData(barData);
```

Getting xAxis values method:

```
private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues()
{
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String> ();

    labels.add( "JAN");
    labels.add( "FEB");
    labels.add( "MAR");
    labels.add( "APR");
    labels.add( "MAY");
    labels.add( "JUN");
    return labels;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't work. Using `barDataSet.getEntryCount()` or `months.length` or simply 12, it's the same. Regarding the dataSets, I'm already doing it that way. `ArrayList<IBarDataSet>` is created after `new BarDataSet(data, "data");`
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Handling axis labels like this can be rather complicated sometimes. You have to first make sure the labels are shown at the interval and spacing you want, then you have to use an axis value formatter to transform them to some other string in this case.

The **TL;DR** is

- `setCenterAxisLabels` does not do what it sounds like it does - don't use it. Labels are *already* centered under their axis values by default. This centers the labels *between* axis values.
- Use numeric labels to debug label position before applying `IndexAxisValueFormatter` to make sure you have integer values in the expected locations.
- `IndexAxisValueFormatter` has some buggy rounding logic and doesn't display labels for values between X.5 and X.999999, while values between X.0 and X.499999 get rounded down to X and `labels[X]` is shown. Use a custom ValueFormatter to fix those issues.

## Long Answer

To start with, I used the following test data, which reproduces the behavior you saw (the behavior will be a bit different if your x values start at 0 instead of 1, but the same type of issues will show up). The code here is in Kotlin, but the solution is equally applicable to Java.

```kotlin
val months = listOf("J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D")
val yvals  = listOf(1f,2f,5f,0.1f,0.5f,1f,0.5f,2f,1f,2.5f,2f,0.2f)

val entries = yvals.mapIndexed { i, y -> BarEntry((i+1).toFloat(),y)}
val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries,"data")
```

**Initial Approach**

When you plot this using your initial chart settings

```kotlin
val xAxis = barChart.xAxis
xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true)
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true)
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true)
xAxis.setLabelCount(months.size, true)
xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(months)
```

you get the first behavior you saw where half the labels are gone and the rest are not positioned under the bars:

[image: case 1]

To better understand why this is happening, we can use a different axis value formatter to see where MPAndroidChart is trying to place labels. This will write the numeric values instead of trying to convert them to array indices:

```kotlin
class VerboseAxisValueFormatter : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
        return "%.2f".format(value)
    }
}
```

This gives (the values match the ones you saw when debugging)

[image: case 2]

Looking at the source code for [`IndexAxisValueFormatter`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/IndexAxisValueFormatter.java)

```java
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    int index = Math.round(value);

    if (index < 0 || index >= mValueCount || index != (int)value)
        return "";

    return mValues[index];
}
```

the final check in there (`index != (int)value`) means that if the rounded value is not equal to the truncated (floor) value then the result is blank. This means that for values from 1.0 to 1.499999 it will return `mValues[1]` but for values from 1.5 to 1.99999 it will return a blank string. That's why the entire first half of the chart was missing labels - the x values it chose to draw axis labels at had decimal portions greater than 0.5.

**Second Approach**

So for your second iteration, you set the label count to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and shifted the values down by 0.5. Doing that here (but leaving the numeric labels on) gives the following, where the labels have nice even spacing (default granularity here is 0.5). If you replaced the integer values here (`0.0`, `1.0`, etc) you would get the result you saw with your "offset label case" (labels were present but not centered)

[image: case 3]

However, the left bar is centered at 1.0 which is very different from where the label was drawn. This is because `xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true)` does not center labels under their values (which would make sense, but that's actually the default behavior already) but instead centers labels *between* the actual axis values. Turning this off and removing the `0.5f` shift, gives

[image: case 4]

Now, we finally have integer value labels centered below bars and in the correct positions, which means we can use the `IndexAxisValueFormatter` - however, the array indices are 0-based and the data set is 1-based. To fix that, you can subtract 1 from the x values either in the data set or in the formatter. Even so, it's not *quite* right - we get an extra label on the left edge because the -0.5 there rounds and truncates to 0.

[image: case 5]

**Working Solution**

In the end, once we have set the label position correctly, the best choice is still to write a custom ValueFormatter that doesn't have all the issues in the built-in `IndexAxisValueFormatter`. Instead of using `index != (int)value` we use `abs(index - x) > 0.01f` so that the behavior is symmetric and only shows labels actually at integer positions.

```kotlin
class FixedIndexAxisValueFormatter(private val offset: Float, private val labels: List<String>) : ValueFormatter()
{
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
        val x = value - offset
        val index = x.roundToInt()
        return if( index < 0 || index >= labels.size || abs(index - x) > 0.01f) ""
               else labels[index]
    }
}
```

Using this formatter finally gives the correct result

[image: case 6]

The final settings to get this were

```kotlin
// Force it to draw labels at all positions controlled by the axis
// bounds and granularity
xAxis.setLabelCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE, true)

// These are already the defaults in this case so they're not necessary, 
// but good to specify explicitly in case the defaults change later
xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.5f
xAxis.axisMaximum = 12.5f
xAxis.granularity = 0.5f

// Use a better value formatter, with an offset of 1 since the
// data set started at 1
xAxis.valueFormatter = FixedIndexAxisValueFormatter(1f, months)
```