# Android - MPAndroid Chart showing x axis value

Tags: java, android, firebase, mpandroidchart

I have a listview with data in one activity and show that data in a graph in another activity. [ListView Data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV8Mk.png) [and displayed on graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcnJe.png)

I want to show the x axis associated with the value("Running", "Swimming")

I'm using an intent to send the value to the graph page and here is the code i'm using to populate the graph.

```
 ArrayList<String> cardioValue = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> cardioCategory = new ArrayList<String>();
    cardioValue = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("cardioValue");
    cardioCategory = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("cardioCategory");


    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<cardioValue.size(); i++ ){

            barEntries.add(new BarEntry( i+1, Integer.parseInt(cardioValue.get(i))));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a value formatter to achieve this.

```
String[] cardioValue = {"", "Running, "Swimming"};
XAxis xaxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xaxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(cardioValue));
```

I have kept the first value of the string array empty because your first bar is being formed at value 1.
You will have to do the same with array lists.

[Link to documentaion.](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface)

[Working example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48824793/indexaxisvalueformatter-not-working-as-expected/48898827#48898827)